# problem with image animation

Tags: iphone

I have  a problem with my image animation.

here is the .h

```
@interface Flash_ViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
IBOutlet UIButton *generateFlash;
IBOutlet UIImageView *theFlash;

IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel;

NSArray *letterArray;
NSMutableArray *imageArray;
NSTimer *myTimer;
int runLoopTimes;
int indexTimes;
}


-(IBAction) generateFlashNow:(id)sender;


@end
```

here is the .m

```
-(IBAction) generateFlashNow:(id)sender{


[textField resignFirstResponder];
/*
NSString *string1 = textField.text;
//NSString *string2 = [string1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"" withString:@","];
NSArray *arrayOfLetters = [string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
*/

NSString *string = textField.text;
NSMutableArray *arrayOfLetters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
    NSString *myChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [string characterAtIndex:i]];
    [arrayOfLetters addObject:myChar];
}

NSLog(@"Log Array :%@", arrayOfLetters);

//NSArray *imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

NSLog(@"Log First Letter of array: %@",[arrayOfLetters objectAtIndex:0]);

runLoopTimes = [arrayOfLetters count];

NSLog(@"Letters:%d", runLoopTimes);



while (runLoopTimes > 0) {
    NSLog(@"loopedy Loop");

    NSString *LetterString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayOfLetters objectAtIndex:indexTimes]];
    runLoopTimes --;
    NSLog(@"letter String : %@", LetterString);

    NSString *imageName =  [LetterString stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
    NSLog(@" IMAGE NAME: %@", imageName);
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    NSLog(@"Added object %d", indexTimes);
    testLabel.text = LetterString;


    indexTimes ++;


}

NSLog(@"done");
runLoopTimes = 0;
indexTimes = 0;

[arrayOfLetters autorelease];
[theFlash setAnimationImages:imageArray];
[theFlash setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
theFlash.animationDuration = 4;
[theFlash startAnimating];
NSLog(@"images flashed");
}
```

and i make
    indexTimes = 0;
in the     viewDidLoad method.

my connections are made in IB, and all log messages fire. But, still i see no animation. What am I doing wrong?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks, Sam

Comment: It's hard to tell from the code you posted what goes wrong.
We should know more about what you did in interface builder (which is not easy to post here...).
Are you sure the theFlash is added to a subview and is visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you create and initialize your imageArray? (you have commented line:`//NSArray *imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];` in your code)
     So for a start make sure that your `imageArray` is not nil and properly initialized. (you can also check its count property to check if images were actually added to it)

Comment: ok, this workd. however, i needed to call NSMutableArray alloc init not just NSArray. therin lies the problem

Comment: yes, you need to use mutable version of array, that line was just a hint to potential problems

Comment: How the hell did it pass '[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];'?

Comment: if imageArray is nil it will work smoothly - you can send any message to nil without any problems.

Comment: yep, you're right. I didn't thougt there would be a Bad_Excess if the alloc is missing.